# InvalidOperationException when first is not found

Tags: c#, linq, invalidoperationexception

I'm trying to find item by item name.

```
Item item = Shop.Items.Values.First(i => i.Name.Contains(partOfName))
```

i expected to do next

```
if (item == null) // if not found
{
    // not found code
}
```

... but when item is not found i got `InvalidOperationException`.

The first thing that comes to mind is

```
try
{
    Item item = Shop.Items.Values.First(i => i.Name.Contains(partOfName))
}
catch(InvalidOperationException ex)
{
    // not found code
}
```

What is the best way to handle it? Maybe without try/catch?

**EDIT.**
Solution:

```
Item item = Shop.Items.Values.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name.Contains(partOfName))

if (item == null) // if not found
{
    // not found code
}
```

Comment: The First method is quite easy to create yourself, so create it yourself

Comment: You can use `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: From the documentation of `Enumerable.First`: "The `First<TSource>` method throws an exception if no matching element is found in source. To instead return a default value when no matching element is found, use the `FirstOrDefault` method."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`First` will throw. `FirstOrDefault` will return the `default<T>`. For reference types, that is `null`.